# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/servlet/weld-servlet/2.1.2.Final

Tags: maven, netbeans, jetty, cdi

I'm trying to deploy a simple Helloworld jsf2.2 project with jetty9.2.3,
I used plugin of netbeans to add the jetty server and to enable jsf and cdi in the server
However, the server never start successfully, it always shows the following error when I'm trying to start jetty server.

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/servlet/weld-servlet/2.1.2.Final/weld-servlet-2.1.2.Final.jar:lib/cdi/weld-servlet-2.1.2.jar
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseHome.getBasePath(BaseHome.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:722)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Java Result: -5
run:
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/servlet/weld-servlet/2.1.2.Final/weld-servlet-2.1.2.Final.jar:lib/cdi/weld-servlet-2.1.2.jar
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseHome.getBasePath(BaseHome.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:722)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Java Result: -5
```

I've googled a lot and find no one come across this problem.
What did I miss? Is there something I need to config?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Stacktrace is for a bad startup configuration.

Sounds like Netbeans is doing something improper for setting up Jetty.  (Possibly a bad weld or cdi module definition)

File a bug with netbeans about their startup.

Answer (score 0):

The error is something wrong at the moment Jetty try to download the library Weld, that enabled CDI in jetty.
Try the following (and sorry for my english :P):

1. Go to the folder where Netbeans created the jetty.base folder (generally in NetBeansProjects folder/JettyServerInstance/jettybase.
2. Open the file jettybase/modules/cdi-weld.mod, copy the link that appear here (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/servlet/weld-servlet/2.1.2.Final/weld-servlet-2.1.2.Final.jar) and download that jar. Copy it to the folder jettybase/lib/cdi/**weld-servlet-2.1.2.jar** (with exactly the name in bold)
3. Modify the line 5 of jettybase/modules/cdi-weld.mod (or in general the line following the [files] section) and keep only the local path to the jar (lib/cdi/weld-servlet-2.1.2.jar).

In case that you enabled JSF support do the following:

1. Go to the folder where Netbeans created the jetty.base folder (generally in NetBeansProjects folder/JettyServerInstance/jettybase.
2. Open the file jettybase/modules/jsf-mojarra.mod, copy the link that appear here (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.5/javax.faces-2.2.5.jar) and download that jar. Copy it to the folder jettybase/lib/jsf/**javax.faces-2.2.5.jar** (with the name in bold)
3. Modify the line 5 of jettybase/modules/jsf-mojarra.mod (or in general the line following the [files] section) and keep only the local path to the jar (lib/jsf/javax.faces-2.2.5.jar).

Let me to know if the previous steps work in your case. Thanks.